# Error:(148) Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined

Tags: build.gradle

Error:(148) Attribute "titleTextColor" has already been defined
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you are defining "titleTextColor" 2 times in XML